# ldapsearch not working

Tags: centos, ldap, centos6

My goal is to test LDAP authentication from command line. I tried using `ldapsearch` for this.

I'm using `Centos 6.7`

Even though I'm using the correct credentials, the following command fails

```
[user@localhost html]# ldapsearch -x -h localhost -p 3389 -b "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com" -W
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

`ldapsearch -x -h localhost -p 3389 -D "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com" -W` also complains  about invalid credentials.

`ldapsearch -x -h localhost -p 3389 -D "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com"` throws `unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed`.

The following is the only thing that works but I'm in need to provide password (authenticate) -

```
ldapsearch -x -h localhost -p 3389 -b "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com"
```

Is there anything I'm missing while trying to supply the password? Could I request help to figure out the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your ldap base really "uid=john.martin,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com"? It could be, but I think that is your binddn, am I right?

When using ldapsearch with simple authentication I use this:

```
ldapsearch -h host -LLL -s sub -x -W -b dc=your,dc=base -Z -D "cn=youruser,ou=org,dc=your,dc=base" ldapfilter attributes
```

Use the manpage of ldapsearch to understand those switches.

You are also using port 3389, which is not normally used for ldap (rather for Windows remote desktop). It is possible to run an ldap server on that port, obviously, but maybe that was a typo?

Comment: Thankyou Natxo. This helped. The port looks weird coz am tunneling it on to the local linux box